# ACCESS VBA Picture saved as OLE OJECT used as Picture property for custom command bar

Tags: vba, image, ms-access-2016

I have some custom popup menus in my app and i am tired of using the .FaceID property just to set some "not so relevant" images form my commands. What i want to do is to get some pictures saved in a local table OLE-OBJECT field and display those instead of the MS pictures.
The controls of commandbar object have .Picture and .Mask properties which work just fine if i load a file from the hdd into a IPictureDisp object using stdole.LoadPicture, but i don't want to have hundres of small files in my app folder.
So, my question is: is there a way i can get the picture saved in the local table to become a IPictDisp. I can get it's byte array just fine, but i found no way of converting that into something that the Commandbar button can recognize.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What type of image files are the images in the OLE-Object field?

Comment: Bitmap by default.